# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Not Expanding

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3 to make my webpage scale to any screen size and the navbar is not expanding when the trigger button is pressed.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS: Bootstrap 3 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript:Bootstrap 3 -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Webpage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Webpage</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"  data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar3">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle nav</span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav collapse navbar-collapse">
                <li class="active"><a href="/p1">Page1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/p2">Page2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/p3">Page3</a></li>
              </ul>
      </div>
      </nav>

      <div id="content">

      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is going wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery needs to load first so it's dependencies can used the library. Since `bootstrap.min.js` is jQuery dependant, you should load it **AFTER** jQuery is loaded.

Just move your jQuery file `jquery.min.js` **before** your bootstrap js file `bootstrap.min.js` and your navbar should work fine.

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript:Bootstrap 3 -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```